# In Typescript, how can I specify the return type of a function that can return multiple types?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a reusable method `getFilters` that can return a number of different types

```
getFilters(): IListFilteringType {...}
```

```
type IListFilteringTypeMultiSelect = (string | number)[];
type IListFilteringType = boolean | string | number | IListFilteringTypeMultiSelect;
```

When I call `getFilters` how can I specify that I know that the returned value with be of type `IListFilteringTypeMultiSelect` and not one of the other possible values of `IListFilteringType`?

Thank you

Comment: _How_ do you know? There might be a more elegant solution here.

Comment: Does the type of the parameters passed to the function influence the type of the return in a deterministic way? In that case try [overload signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads). If there is no way to tell based on the arguments which of the types will be returned, then use a union type as you have already, and cast the result using `as`, as described in Woohaik's answer.

Comment: Multiple return types is a sign that your function does too much. Split it in smaller functions that return only one type and they will be easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure about the type of the return of the function for a particular execution, you could cast the return value using `as`.

```
const variable = functionResponse as IListFilteringTypeMultiSelect;
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this into some sort of conditional? Like, maybe if the function returns a boolean, I want to do X, but if the function returns a string I want to do Y? 
I'm guessing something like if (variable as boolean) { /*X*/ } else if (variable as string) (v{ /*Y*/}?

Comment: You could use conditionalls, use the `as` inside each `if` and do the corresponding loginc to each other inside the same `if` to avoid type errors, but this aggregates much complexity since this needs to be done every time you call the function. Consider separate the job.